# How to specify solr string in chef-vault

Tags: solr, chef-infra

I use chef-vault to store some of my secret data in chef-server, and then only some of my hosts specified by the -S option when create/update the vault can retrieve the encrypted data. Using the below command to create/update a vault:

```
knife vault create secrets key1 --json key1.json --admins admin --mode client -S 'name:pre1.host1'
```

Then the host "pre1.host1" can retrieve the encrypted data. My question is:
Can I designate the hosts by regular expression(only including the prefix or suffix or some other part). Or I must designate every host one by one, it is inefficient. I have googled the question for much time, but did not get it.

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the host by a search as you would do with `knife search node` ot within a recipe.

[Search documentation is here](https://docs.chef.io/knife_search.html)